# excel pivot table - multiple label filters

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table

Is there a way to exclude multiple labels in a pivot table?

I would like to exclude 3 channels from the channel column in the pivot table below. I thought Label Filter would do the trick but no luck so far...

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using a slicer? Create a slicer for Channel, and using `ctrl + click` you can add/remove values from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you can build a slicer to select/deselect multiple items by holding `ctrl` whilst selecting with the mouse.

[image]